# Finding gallons of milk for $2$%

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many gallons of milk that is $2$% butterfat must be mixed with milk that is $3.5$% butterfat to get $10$ gallons that are $3$% butterfat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up the following system

> $$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   {.02x + .035y = .03 \cdot 10} \\ 
>   {x + y = 10} 
> \end{array}} \right.$$

Where $x$ is the number of gallons of $2\%$ milk and $y$ is the number of gallons of $3.5%$. Then, solve this system using standard techniques (such as add/subratcing equations or substitution) to obtain,

> $$x = \frac{10}{3} \text{gallons} \ \ \ \text{and } \ \ \ y = \frac{20}{3} \text{gallons.}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If we take $100x$ gallons of the milk with $3.5$% butter and $100y$  gallons of the milk with $2$% butter,

we get $100(x+y)$ gallons of milk with $(3.5x+2y)$ gallons of butter

We need $3.5x+2y=100(x+y)\cdot3$%$=3x+3y\implies x=2y\ \ \ \ (1)$

and $100(x+y)=10\ \ \ \ (2)$

Solve for $x,y$ using $(1),(2)$

Comment: $x=2y$ how did you found this ? can explain this step ?

Comment: @SSK, $3.5x+2y=3x+3y\implies (3.5-3)x=(3-2)y\implies .5x=y$

Comment: how did u found $10$ ?

Comment: @SSK, read the last part of the Question : "get $10$ gallons that are $3$% butterfat"

Comment: Yeah that'r right

Comment: if i am doing $100(2y+y) = 10$  , $300y = 10 $ , $y= 10/300$

Comment: @SSK, so we need $100\cdot \frac{10}{300}$ litre $=\frac{10}3$ litre of the  the milk with $2$% butter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9259/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-ssk)